# How to keep array-data exclusive in p5.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, p5.js

I have 3 arrays key_1, key_2, key_3 they each have 2 values that serve as x & y coordinates. When I run the code I expect 9 circles of 3 different colours but instead the colours get mixed up. I dont know why or how to fix it, any clues

```
let key_1 = [], key_2 = [], key_3 = [];

function setup() {

  createCanvas(790, 800);

  for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    let x = random(0, width);
    let y = random(0, height);
    key_1.push([i, x, y]);
  };

  for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    let x = random(0, width);
    let y = random(0, height);
    key_2.push([i, x, y]);
  };

  for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    let x = random(0, width);
    let y = random(0, height);
    key_3.push([i, x, y]);
  };
};



function draw() {
  background(0);

  for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    //expect 3 red circles, I'll get  2 red circles and 1 either green or blue
    ellipse(key_1[i][1], key_1[i][2], 5, 5);
    fill('rgba(100,0,0,1)'); noStroke()
  };

  for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    //expect 3 green circles, I'll get  2 green circles and 1 either green or blue
    ellipse(key_2[i][1], key_2[i][2], 10, 10);
    fill('rgba(0,100,0,1)'); noStroke();
  };

  for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    //expect 3 blue circles, I'll get  2 blue circles and 1 either green or blue
    ellipse(key_3[i][1], key_3[i][2], 30, 30);
    fill('rgba(0,0,100,1)'); noStroke();
  };

};
```

Comment: can you show us the rest of the code?

Comment: @LukeGarrigan Full code added

Comment: Seems to work fine for me? I get 3 reds, 3 greens, 3 blues

Comment: @LukeGarrigan That's exactly what you'd think, now change the radius and you'll notice the difference (I'll re-edit the post)

Comment: You might want to use an array rather than `key_1, key_2, key_3` which requires you to dupe your code 3x, prone to bugs and unmaintainable.

Comment: @ggorlen I tried that  **ie let the_data=[[],[],[]]**  and still same error. Unless made some sort of mistake

Comment: Well you're setting the fill color after drawing. First call `fill` and `noStroke` then `ellipse`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple issues with this code, first off I recommend having a read at how `fill` and `noStroke` work in p5.js.

The issue with `noStroke()` is that you're repeating yourself multiple times for no reason. Unless a `noStroke()` is followed by a `stroke()` or wrapped in a [push/pop](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/push) then it is going to remove all the strokes for all shapes you draw within the `draw()` loop.

So simply adding `noStroke()` in your `setup()` function once should suffice:

```js
function setup() {

  createCanvas(790, 800);
  ...
  noStroke();
};
```

Next, you are also repeating yourself with the `fill()`, the same principles apply here. Anything below a `fill()` will be filled with that colour unless another `fill()` is added afterwards. So you only need to write it once before you're looping through to draw the circles:

```js
  ...
  fill('rgba(100,0,0,1)');
  for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    ellipse(key_1[i][1], key_1[i][2], 200,200);
  };

  fill('rgba(0,100,0,1)'); 
  for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    ellipse(key_2[i][1], key_2[i][2], 200, 200);
  };
 ...
```

Lastly, there's quite a lot of repetition and the `i` in your arrays doesn't really serve a purpose. One way to solve this would be to create an array of objects which has the `colour` as well as the `x` and `y`. Something like the following:

```js
let circles = [];

function setup() {
  createCanvas(790, 800);
  const red = "rgba(100,0,0,1)";
  for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    circles.push({
      x: random(0, width),
      y: random(0, height),
      color: red,
    });
  }

  const green = "rgba(0,100,0,1)";
  for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    circles.push({
      x: random(0, width),
      y: random(0, height),
      color: green,
    });
  }

  const blue = "rgba(0,0,100,1)";
  for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    circles.push({
      x: random(0, width),
      y: random(0, height),
      color: blue,
    });
  }
  noStroke();
}

function draw() {
  background(0);
  for (let circle of circles) {
    fill(circle.color);
    ellipse(circle.x, circle.y, 200, 200);
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.4.1/p5.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.4.1/addons/p5.sound.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <meta charset="utf-8" />

  </head>
  <body>
    <main>
    </main>
    <script src="sketch.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The code I used:

```
...
ellipse(key_1[i][1], key_1[i][2], 5, 5);
fill('rgba(100,0,0,1)'); noStroke()
...
```

Correct method of calling it:

```
...
fill('rgba(100,0,0,1)'); noStroke();
ellipse(key_1[i][1], key_1[i][2], 5, 5);
...
```

credit: ggorlen